# Exportar a excel con tablas hijas y nietas

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Dispongo de una tabla en [Jquery Datatables](https://datatables.net/) la cual dispone de tablas hijas y nietas (Una tabla con subtablas que a su vez tienen subtablas) la tabla se forma de la siguiente manera:

```
function cargarTabla() {

    //Función interna para realizar un ajax y obtener las columnas
    mvc.Datos.GetColumnas.post({ IdTabla: idTabla }, res => {
        var datos = res;
        datos = JSON.parse(datos);
        var ruta = idTabla != 17 ? "/Datos/GetDatosPorPuesto?idPuesto=" + idPuesto : "/Datos/GetDatosDocumentacion?idLinea=" + idLinea;

        table = $('#tablaDatos').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                url: ruta,
                dataSrc: function (data) {                              
                    return JSON.parse(data);                                
                }
            },
            "bDestroy": true,
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
            }, select: {
                style: 'multi'
            },
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "columns":
                datos
            ,
            "order": [[3, 'desc']],
            "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                runAllCharts();
            },
            "columnDefs": [{
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return (data == 1) ? '<center><i class="fa fa-check"></i></center>' : ' <center><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></center>';
                },
            }]
        });
        //botones personalizados para exportacion
        var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
            buttons: [
                {
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
                    },                              
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    title: '',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-3x fa-file-code" style="padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px"></i>',
                    className: 'btn btn-default jarvismetro-tile txt-color-white btnTablas',
                    attr: {
                        style: 'background-color:#203864;display:none',
                        id: 'exportJSON'
                    },
                    action: function (e, dt, button, config) {
                        var data = dt.buttons.exportData();

                        $.fn.dataTable.fileSave(
                            new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)]),
                            'Export.json'
                        );
                    }
                },
                {
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
                    },
                    title: '',
                    extend: 'excel',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-3x fa-file-excel" style="padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px"></i>',
                    className: 'btn btn-default jarvismetro-tile txt-color-white btnTablas',
                    attr: {
                        style: 'background-color:#203864;display:none',
                        id: 'exportXls'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }).container().appendTo($('#buttons'));
    });
}

cargarTabla();
```

funcion para generar la subtabla y la subsubtabla:

```
$('#tablaDatos').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {

    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row



        try {
            var d = row.data();
            var parametros = d.Registros;
            nieto = parametros;

            var subtabla;

            subtabla = '<table id = "child_details" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
                '<thead><tr>' +
                '<th></th>' +
                '<th>campo1</th>' +
                '<th>campo2</th>' +
                '<th>campo3</th>' +
                '<th>campo4</th>' +
                '<th>campo5</th>' +
                '<th>campo6</th>' +
                '<th class="hide">campo7</th>' +
                '</tr></thead><tbody>';

            $.each(parametros, function (index, value) {
                subtabla += '<tr><td class="details-control"></td>';
                subtabla += '<td>' + value.campo1 + '</td>';
                subtabla += '<td>' + value.campo2 + '</td>';
                subtabla += '<td>' + value.campo3 + '</td>';
                subtabla += '<td>' + value.campo4 + '</td>';
                subtabla += '<td>' + value.campo5 + '</td>';
                //valores de la tabla nieta
                subtabla += '<td class="hide">' + value.campo6 + '</td>';
                subtabla += '<td>' + value.campo7 + '</td>';

            });
            subtabla += '</tbody></table>';
            row.child(subtabla).show();

            childTable = $('#child_details').DataTable({
                searching: false,
                paging: false,
                info: false,
                destroy: true
            });
            childTable
                .on('select', function (e, dt, type, indexes) {
                    if (type === 'row') {
                        var data = childTable.rows(indexes).data();
                        // do something with the ID of the selected items
                    }
                });
            tr.addClass('shown');
        } catch {

            var d = childTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
            var parametros = JSON.parse(d[6]);
            $.each(parametros, function (index, value) {
                console.log(index, value);
                if (index == "Aprietes") {
                    nieceTable = '<table id = "niece_details" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
                        '<thead></thead><tbody>' +
                        '<tr><td>Apriete:</td>';
                    $.each(value, function () {
                        nieceTable += '<td>' + this.APRIETE + '</td>';

                    });
                    nieceTable += '</tr><tr><td>Par:</td>';
                    $.each(value, function () {
                        nieceTable += '<td>' + this.PAR + '</td>';
                    });
                    nieceTable += '</tr><tr><td>Angulo:</td>';
                    $.each(value, function () {
                        nieceTable += '<td>' + this.ANGULO + '</td>';
                    });
                    nieceTable += '</tr></tbody></table>';
                } else {
                    nieceTable = '<table id = "niece_details" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
                        '<thead><tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Valor</th></tr></thead><tbody>' +
                        '<tr><td>' + this.Title + '</td>' +
                        '<td> ' + this.Value + '</td>' +
                        '</tr></tbody></table>';
                }
            });

            childTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).child(nieceTable).show();

            var nieceTable = $('#niece_details').DataTable({
                searching: false,
                paging: false,
                info: false,
                destroy: true,
                scrollY: '50px',
                select: true,
            });
            nieceTable
                .on('select', function (e, dt, type, indexes) {
                    if (type === 'row') {
                        var data = childTable.rows(indexes).data();
                        // do something with the ID of the selected items
                    }
                });
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    }
});
```

Con esta configuración se me muestran correctamente los botones de exportación pero al pulsarlo solo se exporta la tabla padre. Estoy usando [Html5 buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html)
Para exportar estoy usando [esta librería](https://github.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin).

He tratado de obtener la tabla hija por medio del action de los botones con [esto](https://datatables.net//forums/discussion/43133) pero sin resultado.

No puedo hacer lo mismo que la tabla hija (añadir los campos en oculto), no he logrado hacerlo mejor dicho.

**¿Como puedo lograr que me exporte la tabla y sus respectivas subtablas?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Soy un usuario mas activo en el foro de habla ingles pero hoy decidí dar una vuelta por acá, debo decir que esto me tomo un buen tiempo y que a pesar de haber hecho cosas complejas en DataTables esto fue un dolor de cabeza pero luego de unas cuantas tazas de café y testeos en jsfiddle espero que sea de utilidad.

1. Primero Cabe aclarar que busque un ejemplo hecho en el foro de DataTables de una tabla que contenga tablas
   hijas y nietas para poder resolver este inconveniente lastimosamente
   perdí el enlace al mismo debido a que chrome murió por tanta tab abierta .
2. Actualmente la librearía que se utiliza para exportar por parte de DataTables no puede capturar la data de las tablas nietas o hijas esto lo puedes ver a detalle en el método customizedData de buttons, si te preguntas porque? es porque la librería envía el texto de cada td equiparándolo a una celda, por ende no captura objetos complejos.
3. **customizedData** tal y como se refleja en esta [pregunta](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/161615/#Comment_161615) del foro de DataTables puede modificar el contenido de nuestra data por lo que es posible sobre escribir esta data para obtener el resultado deseado desde Ajax o para este caso usando [orthogonal](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33305/exporting-data-from-the-source-data-rather-than-from-a-displayed-table-cell) este nos permite exportar data desde la fuente de datos de una celda y puesto que en este ejemplo tanto la tabla hija como nieta tienen su source data en una celda pasaremos esta data utilizando `JSON.stringify` para convertir nuestro objeto a un string de esta forma podremos moldear la data en el método **customizedData**
4. Para realizar esto debemos hacer un render sobre la celda que contiene los elementos hijos y nietos en el apartado **columns**.

   ```
   data: "termGPA",
   render: function (data, type, row) {
           return type === 'export' ?
           JSON.stringify(data) : '<imgsrc="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">' ;
   }
   ```

   Este elemento de nuestro JSON contiene los valores de nuestra tabla hija y nieta, aquí indicamos que retornaremos la data encodeada cuando el **type** sea del tipo export y en caso contrario se mostrara el valor default de nuestro icono.
5. Finalmente en el apartado de buttons debemos definir la manera en la que modificara la data, para el caso la mostrare tal cual se vería si las tablas hija y nieta estuvieran expandidas, para ello creamos un arreglo que reemplazara el sub arreglo body de nuestro objeto.

   ```
   buttons: [{
     extend: 'excelHtml5',
     customizeData: function(data) {
       let subchild = data.body;
       var exportBody = [];
       var secondTable = ["", "Term", "GPA Value"];
       var thirdTableName = ["", "Course Name", "Letter Grade"];
       subchild.forEach((e, i) => {
         let row = JSON.parse(e[0]);
         exportBody.push([i + 1, e[1], e[2], e[3], e[4]]);
         row.forEach((el, idx) => {
           let subrow = el;
           exportBody.push(secondTable);
           exportBody.push(["", el.term, el.gpaValue]);
           exportBody.push(thirdTableName);
           subrow.termCourseGrades.forEach((grade, pos) => {
             exportBody.push(["", grade.courseName, grade.letterGrade]);
           })
         })
       })
       data.body.length = 0;
       data.header[0] = "Row";
       data.body.push.apply(data.body, exportBody);
     },
     exportOptions: {
       orthogonal: 'export'
     }
   }]
   ```

En este apartado debemos tener en cuenta que al ser el atributo data de nuestra columna distinto de **null** esta sera tomada en cuenta para generar el documento por lo que puedes dejar un espacio para cada celda o agregar data para que la columna que equivalga al numero de fila del registro.

Finalmente no decidí utilizar la librería que mencionas en la pregunta ya que nunca antes la he usado y preferí utilizar las librerías que provee DataTables para exportar.

Espero sea de ayuda saludos.

```js
var iTermGPACounter = 1;
var iCourseCounter = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadDetailsByCourse();
});


function loadDetailsByCourse() {
  var yearTable = $('#msGrades').DataTable({
    data: [{
      "__type": "DMC.WebServices.detailGPA",
      "schoolYearLabel": "14-15",
      "schoolLevel": "02",
      "location": "Highland",
      "grade": "7",
      "gpaValue": "3.119",
      "termGPA": [{
        "term": "1",
        "gpaValue": "3.857",
        "termCourseGrades": [{
          "courseNo": "38929712",
          "sectionNo": "200",
          "courseName": "HEALTH 2",
          "letterGrade": "A+",
          "department": "EL"
        }, {
          "courseNo": "32320711",
          "sectionNo": "10",
          "courseName": "LANG ARTS 2",
          "letterGrade": "A+",
          "department": "EL"
        }, {
          "courseNo": "32720711",
          "sectionNo": "10",
          "courseName": "MATH 2",
          "letterGrade": "B",
          "department": "MA"
        }]
      }, {
        "term": "2",
        "gpaValue": "3.714",
        "termCourseGrades": [{
          "courseNo": "38929712",
          "sectionNo": "200",
          "courseName": "HEALTH 2",
          "letterGrade": "A",
          "department": "EL"
        }, {
          "courseNo": "32320711",
          "sectionNo": "10",
          "courseName": "LANG ARTS 2",
          "letterGrade": "A",
          "department": "EL"
        }, {
          "courseNo": "32720711",
          "sectionNo": "10",
          "courseName": "MATH 2",
          "letterGrade": "A-",
          "department": "MA"
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "__type": "DMC.WebServices.detailGPA",
      "schoolYearLabel": "15-16",
      "schoolLevel": "02",
      "location": "Highland",
      "grade": "8",
      "gpaValue": "3.123",
      "termGPA": [{
        "term": "1",
        "gpaValue": "3.143",
        "termCourseGrades": [{
          "courseNo": "32320711",
          "sectionNo": "12",
          "courseName": "LANG ARTS 2",
          "letterGrade": "A",
          "department": "EL"
        }, {
          "courseNo": "32720711",
          "sectionNo": "12",
          "courseName": "MATH 2",
          "letterGrade": "D",
          "department": "MA"
        }]
      }]
    }],
    paging: false,
    columns: [
      {
        className: 'term-details-control',
        orderable: false,
        data: "termGPA",
         render: function (data, type, row) {
                return type === 'export' ?
                  JSON.stringify(data) : '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">' ;
         }, 
        defaultContent: '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">'
      }, {
        data: "schoolYearLabel"
      }, {
        data: "grade"
      }, {
        data: "location"
      }, {
        data: "gpaValue"
      }
    ],
    order: [
      [1, 'asc']
    ],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'excelHtml5',
      customizeData: function(data) {
       let subchild = data.body;
       var exportBody = [];
       var secondTable = ["","Term","GPA Value"];
       var thirdTableName = ["","Course Name","Letter Grade"];
       subchild.forEach((e,i)=>{
       let row = JSON.parse(e[0]);
       exportBody.push([i+1,e[1],e[2],e[3],e[4]]);
       row.forEach((el,idx)=>{
       let subrow = el;
       exportBody.push(secondTable);
       exportBody.push(["",el.term,el.gpaValue]);
       exportBody.push(thirdTableName);
       subrow.termCourseGrades.forEach((grade,pos)=>{
       exportBody.push(["",grade.courseName,grade.letterGrade]);
       })
       })
       })
      data.body.length = 0;
      data.header[0] = "Row";
      data.body.push.apply(data.body, exportBody);
      },
       exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
    }]
  });

  // Add event listener for opening and closing details
  $('#msGrades tbody').on('click', 'td.term-details-control', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = yearTable.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
      // Open this row
      row.child(formatTermGPA(iTermGPACounter)).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');

      var termTable = $('#termGPA_' + iTermGPACounter).dataTable({
        data: row.data().termGPA,
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        columns: [{
          className: 'course-details-control',
          orderable: false,
          data: null,
          defaultContent: '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">'
        }, {
          data: "term"
        }, {
          data: "gpaValue"
        }],
        order: [
          [1, 'asc']
        ]
      });

      // Add event listener for opening and closing details
      $('#termGPA_' + iTermGPACounter + ' tbody').on('click', 'td.course-details-control', function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var closestTable = tr.closest("table");
        var row = closestTable.DataTable().row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
          // This row is already open - close it
          row.child.hide();
          tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
          // Open this row
          row.child(formatTermCourseGrades(iCourseCounter)).show();
          tr.addClass('shown');

          var courseTable = $('#courseGrades_' + iCourseCounter).DataTable({
            data: row.data().termCourseGrades,
            paging: false,
            searching: false,
            columns: [{
              data: "courseName"
            }, {
              data: "letterGrade"
            }],
            order: [
              [1, 'asc']
            ]
          });

        }

        iCourseCounter += 1;
      });

      iTermGPACounter += 1;
    }
  });
}

function formatTermGPA(table_id) {
  return '<table class="table table-striped" id="termGPA_' + table_id + '">' +
    '<thead><tr><th></th><th>Term #</th><th>Term GPA</th></tr></thead></table>';
}

function formatTermCourseGrades(table_id) {
  return '<table class="table table-striped" id="courseGrades_' + table_id + '">' +
    '<thead><tr><th>Course Name</th><th>Letter Grade</th></tr></thead></table>';
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in col-xs-12" id="Grades">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6" align="center">
        <label style="width: 75%">
          <h3>Middle School Grades</h3>
        </label>
        <table id="msGrades" class="tblGrades" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>School Year</th>
              <th>Grade</th>
              <th>School</th>
              <th>GPA</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```