# Generar excel desde un datatable con padre e hijas

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

Dispongo de una tabla con hijas en [datatable](https://datatables.net/) y necesito hacer una exportación de los datos a excel. Al ser necesaria una customización de los datos, he creado una función que devuelve los datos ya preparados pero al momento de exportar solo me muestra los padres, cuando lo que he realizado me devuelve el padre que ha sido seleccionado junto sus hijos.

Estoy usando los botones de exportación [excelHtml5](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5) y para definir el botón tengo:

```
    {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-3x fa-file-excel" style="padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px"></i>',
        className: 'btn btn-default jarvismetro-tile txt-color-white btnTablas',
        attr: {
            style: 'background-color:#203864;display:none',
            id: 'exportXls'
        },
        customizeData: function (data) {                                        
        CrearExcel(data);
        console.log("Datos postProcesados", data);     

    },exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
```

Funcion CrearExcel():

```
function CrearExcel(datos) {
                var padre = [];
                var exportBody = [];
                var numero = 1;
                var parametros = [];
                var subchild = EncontrarNieta();

                mvc.Datos.GetProcedimiento.post({ IdPuesto: idPuesto, NumSerie: numserie }, res => {
                    parametros = res;
                    //console.log("data",data);
                    console.log("subchild", subchild);


                    subchild.forEach((e) => {
                        if (e.NumSerie == numserie) {
                            padre.push(e.Fecha, e.NumSerie, e.Resultado, e.NombreResponsable, e.Comentario);
                        }
                    });

                    $.each(parametros, function (index, h) {
                        //console.log("h", h)
                        exportBody.push([numero, padre[0], padre[1], padre[2], padre[3], padre[4], h.Fecha, h.Operacion, h.Titulo, h.Valor, h.Resultado, h.Nombre]);
                        numero++;
                    });
                    //console.log("exportBody", exportBody);
                    //console.log("data", data);
                    datos.body.length = 0;
                    datos.header[0] = "Row";
                    datos.header[1] = "Fecha";
                    datos.header[2] = "Numero de Serie";
                    datos.header[3] = "Resultado";
                    datos.header[4] = "Responsable";
                    datos.header[5] = "Comentario";
                    datos.header[6] = "Fecha";
                    datos.header[7] = "Operacion";
                    datos.header[8] = "Registro";
                    datos.header[9] = "Valor";
                    datos.header[10] = "Resultado";
                    datos.header[11] = "Operario";
                    datos.body.push.apply(datos.body, exportBody);
                    //datos = data;
                    return datos;
                });
            }
```

El resultado del console log es el deseado, los datos bien organizados y estructurados como yo quiero, pero al abrir el excel solo salen los padres.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el excel sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo esto está vinculado a [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/316910/101499) que recibí para hacer lo mismo pero con hijos y nietos

> **¿Por qué no pinta el excel con los datos?**

Comment: Podrias probar sacar la data que retornas y hacer el apply afuera de la funcion, si eso no resulta podrías adjuntar un jsfiddle funcional para revisar el problema con la estructura de datos que posees

Comment: La captura viene de fuera de la funcion, voy a construir un jsfiddle con mi problema

Comment: @stanchacon te dejo el [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsp7hom5/12/) Esta casi igual que como lo tengo en mi proyecto, pero me debe faltar algo porque no logro hacer funcionar el boton que despliega los botones de exportacion

Comment: Tienes que dejar un ejemplo funcional para poder ayudarte, revise y le faltan elementos a tu archivo el evento del botón exportar invoca elementos que no tienes en tu HTML?? deja un archivo funcional por favor

Comment: He logrado hacer que [funcione](https://jsfiddle.net/t3nyh1ge/117/) con llamadas ajax sin embargo no es optimo ya que que el metodo customizedData no funciona con codigo asincrono, por lo que deberias cambiar la manera en que se forman las tablas para tener la data disponible en customizedData es decir que en tu backend deberias devolver un json que contenga no solo la tabla principal si no las hijas en tu llamada inicial

Comment: Gracias @stanchacon, por lo menos ya se que es lo que ocurría con customizedData, el problema es que no puedo pasarle los datos con las hijas ya que causaba lentitud en el proceso y se demoraba hasta 20 minutos en mostrar la tabla (Bendito Big Data). Seguiré investigando como lograrlo, seguro que hay alguna manera de engañarlo y lograr mi objetivo. Un saludo y gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Mi opinión es que deberías cargar las hijas y almacenarlas cada vez que consulte el usuario e imprimir solo las que consulta el usuario, como tu dices es demasiada data para obtenerla toda de una vez, asi que hacer que tu datatable sea por post proceso es lo mejor